# problem during Installation of Ubuntu in windows 11

Tags: system-installation

I am using windows 11 in my laptop. I want to install ubuntu under windows subsystem for linux in windows 11. I have downloaded and install windows subsystem for linux application from microsoft store. I have enabled virtual machine platform and windows subsystem for linux options under windows features.Then from microsoft store I have downloaded ubuntu but whenever I am going to open it there is showing some error messages. Here I have attached the screenshot of error showing page.
Please help me to resolve the problem as soon as possible.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzofn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCX12.png)

Comment: Sounds like you installed WSL but never actually installed Ubuntu on it. Install WSL.
Download Ubuntu.
Configure Ubuntu.
Install your first package.
Customising your Terminal with Windows Terminal Preview.
Enjoy Ubuntu on WSL!

Comment: A tutorial for you to follow. Works for windows 11 as well. https://linuxhint.com/install_ubuntu_windows_10_wsl/

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1436854/231142